# Why All the buttons that I have are not clickable?

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-modal

**Problem:** None of the buttons on my GUI are clickable.

It's been Five days and I can't find any solution to this problem.  I can't click any of my buttons on my form because all of my buttons are Modals.  Could anyone check my code please? I badly needed help from you, hoping you will help me.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../db_connection.php");
?>
<?php
include("get_specific_food.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  <link href="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
   <?php
    include("seller_navigation.php");
    ?>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">

              <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </span>

              </div>
            <br>

                <?php
                $seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
                $image_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT s_image FROM seller
                WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");

                $image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_query);
                ?>

            <?php $img = "upload/" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "." . $image['s_image']; ?>
            <center><img class="rounded-circle" src="upload/<?php echo $image['s_image']; ?>" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
             <p class="lead"><?php echo $_SESSION["s_fname"]; ?></p></center>


              <!--  <p class="lead">Shop Name</p>-->
                     <center><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodall">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span> <b>Add an Information</b>
                    </button></center></p>
                <!--<center>-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mymodall">
                        <div class= "modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">


                                    <form action="db_add_selling_details.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></center>
                                    <?php// $img = "upload/" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "." . $image['s_image']; ?>
                                    <center><img class="rounded-circle" src="upload/<?php //echo $image['s_image']; ?>" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140"><br><br>

                                        <b>Add Profile Pic:</b><br><input style="background-color: #003333;" class="btn btn-info" name ="s_image" type="file"/>
                                    </H5>
                                </div>
                                </center>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                <H5><b>Opening Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_time" ><br>
                                    <b>Days:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_days" ><br>
                                    <b>Order Cut off Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="order_cutoff" ><br>
                                    <b>Delivery Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="seller_delivery_time"><br>
                                    <b>Area Covered of Delivery:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="area_covered_delivery"><br>
                                    <b>Delivery Fee:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="delivery_fee">
                                </H5>
                                    </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <input type ="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" />

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                            </center>

                            </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>



                          <center><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> <b>Update Information</b>
                    </button></center></p>
                <!--<center>-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
                        <div class= "modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">

                                    <?php
                                        $seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
                                        $user_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT seller.s_fname, seller.trade_name, seller.s_address, seller.s_image, selling_details.opening_time, selling_details.opening_days, selling_details.order_cutoff, selling_details.seller_delivery_time, selling_details.area_covered_delivery, selling_details.delivery_fee FROM seller INNER JOIN selling_details ON seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id
                                        WHERE seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id and
                                        seller.seller_id=".$_SESSION['seller_id']);

                                        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query);
                                        ?>
                                    <form action="db_selling_details.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></center>
                                    <?php $img = "upload/" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "." . $user['s_image']; ?>
                                    <center><img class="rounded-circle" src="upload/<?php echo $user['s_image']; ?>" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                                    <H5><b>Seller:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_fname" value="<?php echo $user['s_fname']; ?>"><br>
                                        <b>Trade Name:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="trade_name" value="<?php echo $user['trade_name']; ?>"><br>
                                        <b>Location:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_address" value="<?php echo $user['s_address']; ?>"><br>
                                        <b>Change Profile Pic:</b><br><input style="background-color: #003333;" class="btn btn-info" name ="s_image" type="file"/>
                                    </H5>
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-body">

                                <!--<center>-->

                                <!--<div class="well">-->
                                <H5><b>Opening Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_time" value="<?php echo $user['opening_time']; ?>"><br>
                                    <b>Days:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_days" value="<?php echo $user['opening_days']; ?>"><br>
                                    <b>Order Cut off Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="order_cutoff" value="<?php echo $user['order_cutoff']; ?>"><br>
                                    <b>Delivery Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="seller_delivery_time" value="<?php echo $user['seller_delivery_time']; ?>"><br>
                                    <b>Area Covered of Delivery:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="area_covered_delivery" value="<?php echo $user['area_covered_delivery']; ?>"><br>
                                    <b>Delivery Fee:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="delivery_fee" value="<?php echo $user['delivery_fee']; ?>">
                                </H5>
                                    </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <input type ="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" />
                                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>-->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                            </center>

                            </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>

                            <center><p><button style="background-color:  #003333;" type="buton" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodaly">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ruble'></span> <b>Sell Food Product</b>
                        </button></center></p>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="mymodaly">
                        <div class= "modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4><b><img class="rounded-circle" src="images/size.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140"><br><br><center>Sell your<br> Product</center></b></h4>
                                    <form action="db_add_food.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></center>
                                    <H5><b>Food Name:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="food_name"><br>
                                        <b>Price:</b><br><input type="number" class="form-control" name="f_price"><br>
                                        <b>INGREDIENTS:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_ingredients"><br>

                                        <b>Product Status:<br> <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="f_status" value="available">AVAILABLE</label>
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="f_status" value="unavailable">UNAVAILABLE</label><br><br>

                                        <b>Date Posted: <input placeholder="date" class="form-control" name="date_posted" type="date" class="validate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"><br>
                                        <b>Change Photo:</b><br><input style="background-color: #003333;" class="btn btn-info" name="f_image" type="file"/>

                                    </H5>

                                            </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <input type ="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" />
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </form>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

        <!--dito ung search dati-->



              </div>
              <br><br>

            <?php


$query1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ordering_system",$query1);
global $food_id;
$start=0;
$limit=6;

if(isset($_GET['food_id']) )
{
    $food_id=$_GET['food_id'];
    $start=($food_id-1)*$limit;
}


$query=mysql_query("select * FROM food_product WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' LIMIT $start, $limit");


while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    echo "<div class='col-sm-3'><div class='panel panel-default' style='border-color:#003333;'>
            <div class='panel-heading' style='color:white;background-color : #003333;'>
            <center> 
    <textarea style='text-align:center;background-color: white;' class='form-control' rows='1' disabled>".$query2['food_name']."</textarea>
            </center>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-body'>
           <a class='fancybox-buttons' href='food_upload/".$query2['f_image']."' data-fancybox-group='button' title='Page ".$food_id."- ".$query2['food_name']."'>

                    <img src='food_upload/".$query2['f_image']."' class='img img-thumbnail'  style='width:350px;height:150px;' />
                    </a>


                    <center><h4> Price: &#8369; ".$query2['f_price']." </h4></center>


                <button style='background-color:  #003333;' type='buton' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal1'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> <b>Update</b> 
                    </button>
                    <span class='pull-right'><b>".$query2['f_status']."</b></span>


                <div class='modal fade' id='mymodal1<?php echo $food_id;?>'>
                <div class= 'modal-dialog'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                        <div class='modal-header'>

                            <h4><b><img class='rounded-circle' src='images/adobe.jpg' alt='Generic placeholder image' width='140' height='140'><br><br><center>Update your<br> Product</center></b></h4>

                            <H5><b>Food Name:</b><br><input type='text' class='form-control' value='Adobo'><br>
                                <b>Price:</b><br><input type='text' class='form-control' value='Php50.00' /><br>
                                <b>INGREDIENTS:</b><br><textarea class='form-control'>Pork,soy,potato,paminta,sibuyas,bawang</textarea><br>
                                <b>Change Photo:</b><br><input style='background-color: #003333;' class='btn btn-info' type='file'/>
                                        <br>
                                <div class='radio'>
                                <label><input type='radio' name='optradio'>Available</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class='radio'>
                                <label><input type='radio' name='optradio'>Unavailable</label>
                                </div>

                            </H5>
                        </div>


                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal' onclick='UpdateFunction()'>Update</button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>

</div>

</center>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>



            </div>
          </div>
        </div>";


}

echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "</div>";




$food_id=NULL;
$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food_product WHERE seller_id = '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] .  "' "));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);

if($food_id>1)
{
    echo "<a href='?food_id=".($food_id-1)." class='button'></a>";
}
else if($food_id!=$total)
{
    echo "<a href='?food_id=".($food_id+1)." class='button'></a>";
}

echo "<ul class='pagination pagination-md'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$food_id) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

            else { echo "<li><a href='?food_id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
echo "</ul>";
?>

                    <!--<center>-->

    <!-- /.container -->

<div class="container">

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

 <script>
function UpdateFunction() {
    alert("Successfully Updated!");
}
</script>

 <script>
function CreateFunction() {
    alert("Successfully Created!");
}
</script>


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Sir I've edited my question, I can't click all my buttons, please Help me

Comment: I don't see any considerable amount of javascript in this heap of code

Comment: @Merigold what do you mean by that sir?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your html is messy. You open a `form` tag, you don't close it properly or you close it where it shouldn't be closed. 
Advice format always your html.

**Problem 1)** You don't use the modal properly as indicated in the bootstrap documentary. Please follow and read examples. Here is a working example for your *Add information* button.(Removed some `center` tags for lisibility purpose).

```
        <!--  <p class="lead">Shop Name</p>-->
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodall">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span> <b>Add an Information</b>

   </button></center></p>
        <!--<center>-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="mymodall">
            <div class= "modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="upload/<?php //echo $image['s_image']; ?>" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140"><br><br>

                                    <b>Add Profile Pic:</b><br><input style="background-color: #003333;" class="btn btn-info" name ="s_image" type="file"/>
                    </div>
                    <form action="db_add_selling_details.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <?php// $img = "upload/" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "." . $image['s_image']; ?>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <H5><b>Opening Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_time" ><br>
                                <b>Days:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="opening_days" ><br>
                                <b>Order Cut off Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="order_cutoff" ><br>
                                <b>Delivery Time:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="seller_delivery_time"><br>
                                <b>Area Covered of Delivery:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="area_covered_delivery"><br>
                                <b>Delivery Fee:</b><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="delivery_fee">
                            </H5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                            <input type ="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" />

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Image Link to what i get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5AIG.png

**Problem 2 :** I see that just before line 215 you are using `mysqli` which is good. And then after, you are using `mysql_*` functions ? These functions are outdated.

Comment: Sir it's still not clickable

Comment: I have tested it.  It works fine for me. Make sure that your jquery and bootstrap.js are well linked.  And you can also insert in your header, Bootstrap CDN, given in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ for test purpose. And let me know.